# Move Div when above Div Filled

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 2 div with relative position 
user with a button fill first Div(innerHTML)
i want second Div move down when first Div Filled

show below link
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/IfaCompany/3NP6F/)

Comment: not getting your question exactly

Comment: I am also not getting your question

Comment: show my demo . a want move second div to down when first div fill

Comment: not clear... please explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NP6F/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' value='Add' onclick='AddEl()' />
    <div style='position:relative;background-color:Red'>
    01
    <div id='Content' style='position:relative;background-color:Green'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style='position:relative;background-color:Blue'>
    Hagh
    <div>
<script>
function AddEl()
{
document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML='Ya';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
​
```

You had the nesting wrong in the `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

It was really hard to understand your question, next time please write full sentences.
But I think I understood what you want to achieve.
You can't just keep open divs, you have to close them. after the div just write `</div>`.
If you open a div inside a div at least have some styling or other content, beside the inner-div, inside the parent-div.
Fix those and it will work for you.

Here is the fixed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='AddEl()' />
<div style='position:relative;background-color:Red'>
01
</div>
<div id='Content' style='position:relative;background-color:Green'>
</div>
<div style='position:relative;background-color:Blue'>
Hagh
</div>
</body>
<script>
function AddEl()
{
document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML='Ya';
}
</script>
</html>
```